# How to set an initial calculated selection interval in Altair

Tags: filter, altair

I am trying to set a calculated initial selection interval in an Altair-viz graph. There are a lot of examples of hardcoding the interval but I cannot find a way to for example choose the last year to now as interval.

I know I can do this in Python, but I need to do it in Altair/Vega-lite grammar as the resulting graph is for use on a webpage with the datasource updating over time.

To add to the complexity we would also like to change the interval using buttons.

The code below (altair=5.0.1) makes the example shown with fixed initial interval and buttons that do not work. I could not find a non failing way to ad the selection filter to the interval.

[image: graph example]

Is what I am trying possible at all?

````
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.sp500.url

options = [{"x": [{"year": 2005, "month": 1}, {"year": 2010, "month": 2}]} ,{"x": [{"year": 2000, "month": 1}, {"year": 2005, "month": 2}]}, None]
labels = ['2005-2010', '2000-2005','All']

input_dropdown = alt.binding_radio(
    options=options,
    labels=labels,
    name='Intervals: ')

selection = alt.selection_point(
    fields=['value'],
    bind=input_dropdown,
)

brush = alt.selection_interval(
    value={
        "x": [{
            "year": 2005,
            "month": 7
        }, {
            "year": 2009,
            "month": 6
        }]
    },encodings=['x']
    )

base = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(alt.X('date:T'),
                                            alt.Y('price:Q')).properties(width=600,
                                                                    height=200)

upper = base.encode(
    alt.X('date:T').scale(domain=brush),
    alt.Y('price:Q').scale(zero=False))

lower = base.properties(height=60).add_params(brush).add_params(
    selection).transform_filter(selection)

graph = alt.vconcat(upper, lower)

graph```
````

Comment: I don't think there is a way to add an interval in a single button. Maybe you could add to dropdown menus instead, one for the minimum year and one for the maximum? Although I personally think that you this info is already part of your lower line graph selection capabilities and the additional radio buttons/dropdown don't add much utility

Comment: Thank you, I don't disagree but there was a request for buttons or some other way to show what was possible. Do you have any idea of how to set the interval dynamically to begin with? Like the last two years?